# Given that the determinant of a matrix is 0 what can be one of the possible eigen values for this matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A matrix $A$ is said to be invertible if $|A| \not= 0.$ Hence for such matrix inverse exist. But what can be said about the eigen values of those matrices, when determinant is zero.

Comment: Well, one of them is $0$, for sure.

Comment: Can you please add a little more explanation? Is this some theorem, that I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\det(A)=0$ you only know that the *product* of the eigenvalues is $0$, which means at least one of them is $0$.

Comment: In general, is this true always? Product of eigen values is equal to determinant of a matrix.

Comment: I just skipped this part. Also checked that trace of a matrix is sum of it's eigen values. Thanks!

Comment: It is always true at least with the commonly used field (i.e real or complex).

Answer (score 2):

$\det(A) = 0$ implies there is a non-trivial solution, $x \ne 0$, to $Ax = 0 = 0\cdot x$. Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.